# Get disabled/inactive products from flat catalog product strucutre

Tags: magento-1.8, php, catalog

I am trying to get all disabled products from magento using the following code but it returns only enabled products. I have enabled Flat Catalog Product options. Is there any way to get disabled configurable products using mysql or magento code?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The disabled products are not indexed in the flat table.
Take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer::updateProductStatus()`. This is called sometime during the indexing process.

```
public function updateProductStatus($productId, $status, $store = null)
{
    if (is_null($store)) {
        foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
            $this->updateProductStatus($productId, $status, $store->getId());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    if ($status == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        $this->_getResource()->updateProduct($productId, $store);
        $this->_getResource()->updateChildrenDataFromParent($store, $productId);
    }
    else { //IF the product is disabled it is removed from the flat tables
        $this->_getResource()->removeProduct($productId, $store);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So you can get the disabled products only by using the EAV tables.
Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED));
```

Answer (score 3):

To get disabled products while you have enabled flat structure,
Try this line before your query

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product', 0);
```

and then you can use your normal query

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED));
```

This will by pass flat structure and get you data from EAV structure

Comment: Perfect answer. Much easier to apply!

Comment: Thanks @RoyToledo :)